# Dynamic WordPress Slider Indicators Not Working

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am creating a WordPress theme and the image slider fails to do three things:

1) When clicking an indicator it does not do anything.

2) The image slider does not slide automatically.

3) The first indicator is never on.

I know the content is present because if I add a Post with the Category slider the image will display along with the title and a new carousel indicator. I also checked the DOM and all of the data-slides are there but nothing is moving. Any help is appreciated.

**HTML/PHP**

```
<?php 
   $number = 0; 
   query_posts('category_name=slider'); 
   if(have_posts()):  
?>

<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <?php while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="<?php echo $number++; ?>"></li>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
  </ol>

  <!-- Carousel items -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">  

    <?php while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>

    <div class="item">
      <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id ( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?><a href=#"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" />
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <?php the_title();?>  
      </div>
    </div></a>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
  </div>
</div>

<?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

**jQuery**

```
//Carousel Indicator
$(".carousel-indicators li:first").addClass("active");
$(".carousel-inner .item:first").addClass("active");
```

Comment: Correct jQuery selector - change :first to :first-child and try if its working

Comment: I tried this to no avail, the slider still does not work.